# Need lesser memory consumption than doing sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD on 99999 variables

Tags: bigdata, scipy

Need lesser memory consumption than doing sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD on 99999 variables.

So I know that I can use TruncatedSVD to do the dimensionality reduction. However, my problem is about choosing the correct amount of `n_components`.

One approach suggested doing TruncatedSVD to the maximum amount of variables first and then calculate on this, how many variables on needs to reach a "explained variance" goal.

But doing the initial TSVD on 99999 variables seems to 1) take a long time (it hasn't finished it) and it 2) slowly seems to occupy all my memory (which I have 120GB).

Comment: So go the other way: increase the number components until you reach the desired level of explained variance. 100K is an absurdly high number of _retained_ features. Welcome to the site.

Comment: @Emre Any other techniques? I thought of calculating the eigenvalues on the covariance matrix and then using the number of > 1 eigenvalues to draw an estimate.

Comment: Use Spark or a different library, such as Armadillo, eigen, or blaze.

Comment: @Emre What about, if finding iteratively the highest amount of variables that the cpu and memory can handle, then how can I act so as to not halt my program, when it hits those limits? I read that it could be possible to catch MemoryError, but in case memory really runs too low, then the program might not have memory to continue and would halt.

Comment: Ask on StackOverflow. Also try out-of-core computation with [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.linalg.svd). Not sure if TruncatedSVD has the same functionality but [IncrementalPCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA) seems to.

Comment: you could use an under-complete shallow linear autoencoder, it learns to span the same subspace as PCA.